Why do some transactions wildly overpay fees?
It's very common to see transactions that pay extremely high fee rates, easily 10, 100, or more times the any reasonable high-priority fee rate.
Who makes these transactions, and why do they overbid to get into blocks?

In those transactions are the fees a negligible amount of the value transferred? Or are they somehow fixed (old wallets used to hardcode fees)?

The fee amount is at the discretion of the transaction author. Assuming the high amount was not either due to software constraints (see @AntoinePoinsot's comment above) or a mistake, you'd have to read their mind to know why an oddly high fee was set.
Here are some speculative reasons:

The transaction is important and the author wants "beyond reasonable doubt" confidence that it'll be confirmed in short order.
The author likes miners and wants to reward them.
The transaction could be at the end of a chain of low or no fee unconfirmed transactions and the author wants to provide incentive for them all to be mined.
The author wants to signal that they think the fee rate equilibrium should be higher.
The author wants to signal that they control plenty of bitcoin.
The author perceives the fee amount to be tied to an elaborate NFT scheme.
If the miner is (or is close to) the author, it could be a way of increasing fee per block metrics (and perhaps upwardly influence the future mean fee). Assuming the transaction is not broadcasted.

